# issue in test classes jar creation(without test classes run only compile) using maven and java

Tags: java, maven, jar

my java project structure looks like below

```
MyJavaProject
   |
   src/main/java
   |
   src/test/java
```

**my project link** https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BytpaaWh1xMbb19XNDd4MURqMmc

**please correct my code**

My pom mentioned below:

**How do i create a test module classes jar and main module classes jar with all maven dependencies**.

Without running test module(only compile) i need to get test jar.**What changes needed to my pom and what maven command i need to mention(or what maven goal i need to mention in eclipse).**

When i used **jar:test-jar** (as per my pom) in the goal field ,test jar created with all classes some times but some times jar contains no class at all.

When i used **compile assembly:single** in the goal field ,main module classes jar created with all dependencies every time.

please can any one help me.i need a sample pom that creates main,test modules of a java project compiled classes jar with maven dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got answer:

```
goal as : mvn clean install -DskipTests

Add this in your pom.xml

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```